# Images appear and disappear on cards on mobile

Tags: html, css, styles

I honestly don't know what is wrong. But when I click on one of the images the other disappear and then re appear.Only happens on the phone, works perfect on desktop. I have no idea what is causing it. You should check the following class styles `.imgcard` and `.card__side` for sure. Happens only on this specific page that I have linked(BB), and not on the other one. Please help!

[Website](https://bravovince.netlify.app/bb.html)

UPDATE: Maybe this is happening only on ios devices.

Comment: share here the code that reproduce your issue (while doing so you might find what goes wrong).

Comment: I did not understand what part of the code to share, so I shared my website. I have been trying to adjust the image and back cards to fit each other on both the pages, that is when this started to happen.